# Timer not executing which defined under UtilityClass constructor

Tags: c#, timer

I would like to execute a C# method every 10 sec and I am using in a  `UtilityClass` class constructor, but method is not executing and I'm not getting any output.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UtilityClass utilityClass = new UtilityClass();
    }
}

public class UtilityClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _Timer;

    public UtilityClass()
    {
        _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds);
        _Timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            ExecuteEvery10Sec();
        };
    }

    private void ExecuteEvery10Sec()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Every 10 sec all at {DateTime.Now}");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems: one - the program immediately terminated, so the timer is destroyed. You should wait to something. For example, waiting 10 minutes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (UtilityClass utilityClass = new UtilityClass()) // To dispose after the use
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000 * 60); // Waits X milliseconds
        }
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

You also can to execute an infinite loop, so the ser exit onlyy by the X button of the console (or by Ctrl+C). So:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (UtilityClass utilityClass = new UtilityClass()) // To dispose after the use
        {
            while (true) { }
        }
    }
}
```

two - You should start the timer, by setting its `Enabled` property to `true`:

```
public class UtilityClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _Timer;

    public UtilityClass()
    {
        _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds);
        _Timer.Enabled = true;
        _Timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            ExecuteEvery10Sec();
        };
    }

    private void ExecuteEvery10Sec()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Every 10 sec all at {DateTime.Now}");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want it to repeat you should also set `_Timer.AutoReset = true;`

Comment: @JonathonK the docs says its the default https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.autoreset?view=netframework-4.8 - "The deafult is true".

Comment: So it does... This is why I shouldn't troll through SO questions in bed... I swear that said the default was false just a couple minutes ago...